# When the back button is pressed Toast is shown but the ondestroy() is not working

Tags: android

The app doesn't close it, remains on the same screen instead of going to home screen?

```
public void  onBackPressed() {   
    Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Bye Bye Have a nice day!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    onDestroy();
}
```

Comment: What is the code in your `onDestroy()` method?

Comment: If you just want to end the app, the `finish()` method is what you are looking for, or the super.onBackPressed() does this for you as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> OnDestroy()

is callback method of activity and should not be called manually. 
To exit from your activity ie. To finish up the activity you need to call

> finish();

method. 
Calling finish() will in turn invoke onDestroy() callback method subsequently where you can handle any windup work if you have.

So your code.may go like this :

```
    public void onBackPressed() {
    Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Bye Bye Have a nice day!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
finish(); }
```

Answer (score 2):

Replace `onDestroy();` with the `super.onBackPressed();`.
`onDestroy()` is one of the Activity's [lifecycle](http://developer.android.com/intl/en/reference/android/app/Activity.html) methods and you shouldn't use it in your code like this. The Android OS will call it when it's needed, it's not intended to be used in your code.

When you need to finish Activity you can use its `finish()` method. In your case, though, you override the method `Activity#onBackPressed()` which by default finishes Activity; hence we can just use its version from the base class to perform its duties.

Comment: Please explain what's the role of super

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
this.finishAffinity();
```

instead of

```
onDestroy();
```

this will end your app